# Comment traduire les « free-range children » faisant l'objet du « free-range parenting » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais

Je suis tombé sur l'article Wikipédia sur le « [free-range parenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-range_parenting) » et on a traduit par « [parentage autonomisant](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=FREE-RANGE%20PARENTING&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) » (Termium, [GDT](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/26552136/parentage-autonomisant)). Dans certains cas quand on aborde le sujet, ou plus généralement, on vient aussi accoler l'adjectif « [free-range](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/free-range) » (« allowed to move around freely : not kept in cages », [tBD](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/free-range)) à l'enfant (*free-range kid(s), children*).

- Comment peut-on traduire le « free-range child/children » ?
- Incidemment connaît-on d'autres traductions de « free-range parenting
  » ?

Comment: Est-ce que *free-range kids* a une connotation sarcastique ou pas du tout ?

Answer (score 1):

En Europe francophone, il ne me semble pas que cette pratique parentale en tant que telle soit très répandue. Si c'est le cas, c'est souvent le terme anglais qui sera adopté par effet de mode, manque de plasticité du français et/ou manque d'imagination.

Pour trouver un équivalent, comme dans bien des cas, on doit recourir à une périphrase. En l'occurrence, ce n'est pas si évident d'en trouver une sans connotation négative comme "enfants livrés a eux-mêmes".

Peut-être :

> Des enfants a l'éducation libérale

> Des enfants très autonomes

> Des enfants éduqués en autonomie / habitués à l'autonomie

Answer (score 1):

Comme un terme familier, je proposerais *un enfant débrouillard* / *une fille débrouillarde* (utilisé par des maîtresses de l'école maternelle, pour caractériser le niveau d'autonomie.)